# JavaScript bases DST on stored date

Tags: javascript, datetime

I am trying to make a gallery of items with associated dates. For example, one item might have a date of 2020-01-20 14:02, while another has a date of 2020-05-02 02:16. All these dates are in a known timezone, and I wish to display them in the timezone of the client (browser), including with DST. However, there is a problem.

```
d = new Date(2020, 01, 20, 14, 02)
```

Thu Feb 20 2020 14:02:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time)

```
d = new Date(2020, 05, 02, 02, 16)
```

Tue Jun 02 2020 02:16:00 GMT-0600 (Mountain Daylight Time)

Depending on the time of year of the date input, the result is either DST or non-DST. How do I display all the dates in the current state of DST rather than the state of DST at the time? Thank you for your help.

Comment: The Date constructor will use the host system settings for timezone offset and daylight saving. If you don't want it to do that, use [*Date.UTC*](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC).

Comment: @RobG I would like it to use the host system setting, but it does not. It uses the time of year of the date setting to decide whether to use DST or not. I want it to be consistent.

Comment: But it's doing the sensible, normal, and logical thing.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Whether it is or isn't, it doesn't make sense for what I'm doing. I want all the dates and times to be displayed in the time of the client, not mixed.

Comment: I understand that, I'm just prompting you to reconsider, because most users in most contexts would expect what it's doing now.

Comment: Assuming the client system is configured how the client requires, which includes settings for daylight saving, then system settings are the time of the client. Some places have daylight saving, some don't. If you start displaying times for standard time when the system is displaying daylight saving time, your users might be a little confused.

Comment: @RobG That's exactly the problem. JavaScript is specifically choosing to display some times in standard even when DST is in effect on the client's system.

Comment: Javascript will display the offset for the specific date. It will not apply the offset for "today" for all dates if on the subject date the offset was something else (usually because of daylight saving but occasionally places change their standard offset too). Wherever a place observes daylight saving, you'll see a different offset for summer and winter times. That behaviour is specified in the language specification, so all compliant implementations will do it.

Comment: @RobG Okay, I understand now. Thank you.